# How to read this Scala declaration?

Tags: scala

In Akka HTTP, a route is of type:

```
type Route = RequestContext ⇒ Future[RouteResult]
```

How to read this? My understanding is that Route is class which behaves like a function which accepts RequestContext type as parameter and returns a Future. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Keyword `type` defines a type alias. So, `Route` is just a type alias for the right side. The right side, `RequestContext ⇒ Future[RouteResult]` is - as you say- a function which accepts `RequestContext` type as parameter and returns a `Future`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that Route is class which behaves like a function
>   which accepts RequestContext type as parameter and returns a Future

You're almost there. `Route` isn't a *class*, it's a [*type alias*](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#type-declarations-and-type-aliases). It doesn't create a new data structure, it allows us to write more concise code which has exactly the same meaning, but usually shorter.

`Route`, as declared, is a function which takes a `RequestContext` and returns a `Future[RouteResult]`, nothing more, nothing less. The upside is that you don't have to write:

```
def foo(route: RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]): Future[RouteResult]
```

But can do:

```
def foo(route: Route): Future[RouteResult]
```